# The codes behind R packages

Tags: r, package

could someone tell how I can see the codes behind the packages in R. 
I tried "?FunctionName", but I am getting only four lines of results even for a complex function.
I want to write my own custom machine learning packages. 
If I understand the code behind other packages, then I will be able to write on my own.
Thanks,
Bill.

Comment: FYI: In some simple cases you can just type in the function name without the question mark. `FunctionName`

Comment: You are very optimistic. I would suggest that you start with reading documentation and tutorials for building a package instead.